# Firebase Android Fragment int null

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-authentication

I make `FragmentViewPost` in Fragment, it shows error. But if I build `ViewPost` not in Fragment project it work. I don't know what issue that makes error in Fragment

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Here is my code:

```
 public class FragmentViewPost extends Fragment {

        public static FragmentViewPost newInstance() {
            FragmentViewPost fragment = new FragmentViewPost();
            return fragment;
        }


        public FragmentViewPost() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_view_post, container, false);
        }

        private RecyclerView mBlogList;
        private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){


                        startActivity();

                    }
                }
            };

            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
            mBlogList = (RecyclerView) mBlogList.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_fragment); <<< Problem

            mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        }

        private void startActivity() {

            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),PageLogin.class);
            loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(loginIntent);

        }


        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(

                    Blog.class,
                    R.layout.blog_row,
                    BlogViewHolder.class,
                    mDatabase

            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                    viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

                }
            };

            mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        }



        public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            View mView;

            public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mView = itemView;
            }

            public void setTitle(String title){

                TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
                post_title.setText(title);
            }

            public void setDesc(String desc){

                TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
                post_desc.setText(desc);
            }

            public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
                ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
            }
        }

    //    @Override
    //    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
    //        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //    }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
        }
    }
```

Detail error:

```
mBlogList = (RecyclerView) mBlogList.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_fragment);
```

Comment: mBlogList = (RecyclerView) mBlogList.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_fragment); <<< Problem

Comment: error line mBlogList @StefanSprenger

Comment: You instantiate mBlogList with mBlogList. It should be: 
mBlogList =  (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_fragment);

Comment: not error but viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage()); error method populateViewHolder @StefanSprenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following code:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_view_post, container, false);
return view;
```

in your `onCreateView()` method.

and change this line:

```
mBlogList = (RecyclerView) mBlogList.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_fragment);
```

with

```
mBlogList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_fragment);
```

Comment: Why you added the View line here? It's not necessary. The main problem is in mBlogList = mBlogList.findViewById.

Comment: Yes, that the main problem, that you are finding the view in a wrong way, that's why is `null`. You need to find the view by id using the `view` object.

Comment: But he gets it inside onViewCreated(View view, Bundle saved...), or do I miss something?

Comment: thx it work! but error method populateViewHolder >> viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage()); @AlexMamo

Comment: Those declaration need to be in `onCreateView()` method and it will work fine. If he moves thise lines inside that method, there will be no problem.

Comment: You need to use `getActivity()` in stead of `getApplicationContext()`. You are extending `Fragment`, that's why you need to use the first method.

Comment: Hey! it work Thank you so much. but CreateOptionMenu not show i want to show and click go to PostActivity. @AlexMamo

Comment: This question is not related with the initial one. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: `@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add){
            goToAttract();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void goToAttract() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Post.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }`@AlexMamo

Comment: If you have an error, you need also to add it in the new question.